# Rank a dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, rank

I have dataframe of the following: Id, DateId, Event, And a whole bunch of other columns. The bare bones though are,

```
set.seed(123)
Id<-c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4),rep(4,4))
DateId<-rep(seq(1,4,1),4)
Event<-round(abs(rnorm(16))*1000,digits=0)
df<-data.frame(Id,DateId,Event)

Id DateId Event
1      1   710
1      2   257
1      3   247
1      4   348
2      1   952
2      2    45
2      3   785
2      4  1668
3      1   380
3      2   919
3      3   575
3      4   608
4      1  1618
4      2    56
4      3   519
4      4   301
```

The other columns are simply more information for each Event. Each column I need for the next step. They are a few factors, integars, and numbers.

What I need to do is rank the DateId column for each Id and make it a new column. In this example it would be the exact same as the DateId column, but I have actual dates in my data, just too time consuming to write a bunch of random semi-sequnetial dates. However, 1=1, 2=2, etc. for the DateId.

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(Rank = dense_rank(DateId))`. It should work if the 'DateId' is actual 'Date' class itself

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to mention that I have more columns than just those 3. I only posted the bare bones of it to keep it simple. Any way to do this in one step and define it as just a column?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as we are creating a new column and assuming that we need only the rank for 'DateId'

Comment: Or is the logic different.  May be you can edit the data to show the expected output along with couple of more columns

Comment: The logic works. However it forms a tibble with the data types below each column name and above the values. It works fine, but nothing serious.

Comment: It is just a print method for tibble,  nothing to worry, if you want as a data.frame, just do `%>% as.data.frame` at the end